# gdal_polygonize with World File

Tags: gdal, vector, geojson, polygonize

I have this image that I want to convert it to GeoJSON.

[image: Image to convert]

And I have this World File:

```
0.0388048118
0.0
0.0
-0.0387897595
697054.11331
4458020.56656
```

When I try to run the gdal_polygonize command from terminal, it pixelizes the json, but If I try to run it without the World File it works very well:

```
gdal_polygonize.py -f "GeoJSON" image.png out.json
```

What can I do to make it work with the World File?
I need the coordinates, so I can't run it without that file...
Is there any alternative to gdal_polygonize?

EDIT

This is what I should get. This GeoJSON has been created without the World File:

[image: What should I Get]

This is what I get with the World File:

[image: What I Get with World File]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with pixelized GeoJSON? It is a vector format and does not have pixels so I guess you see some other artifacts. Link to full resolution source image and good and bad result would help.

Comment: I added some pictures of the GeoJSON so that you can understand more clearly what I mean...

Comment: Really odd. Could we get the source png as well? What GDAL version do you have? The pixel size of the source image seems to be 3.8 cm. Do you think it is OK?

Comment: I have GDAL 1.11.1 
http://postimg.org/image/7nunun7nz/ 
Yes, the pixel size is correct!

Comment: Unfortunately I could not make the GDAL python utilities work with the computer I have on my hands. Let's hope someone else can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your efford, but I just want to ask you one more question... What version do you use of GDAL?

Comment: GDAL 2.0 is just released.

Comment: I managed to test it with GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10 and I can't reproduce your problem. I saved your world file as res_1394_1581_758_945_thresh.wld and run your gdal_polygonize command. The result looks good. Try to create polygons as shapefile and check if that makes any difference for you. The coordinates in the GeoJSON created with world file does not make sense without a named projection because in that case the default is EPSG:4326 but anyway, for me the json opens and look good with QGIS 2.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user30184, I managed to solve the problem.

It seems that the version of the GDAL I had installed, which was 1.11.1, had a problem with the function gdal_polygonize.py.
I installed the newest version of GDAL (2.0.0) and it works perfectly!